# What do I need to do to make a Teams bot callable

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to create a Microsoft Teams bot that can be called. Especially, we plan to use it as a destination for incoming calls on a Call Queue.

It seems that the call buttons
[image]
we usually get with contacts are nowhere to be seen on this bot:
[image]

So far, I have managed to create a bot according to the samples.

In https://dev.botframework.com/, the bot appears and I have the `Enable Calling` flag set (which - interestingly, seems to get disabled almost every time I run the project in Visual Studio).

[image]

My permissions.json looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "delegated": [
      "User.Read"
    ],
    "application": [
      "Calls.Initiate.All",
      "Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All",
      "Calls.JoinGroupCall.All",
      "Calls.AccessMedia.All"
    ]
  }
]
```

My manifest.template.json looks like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.13/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.13",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "id": "{{state.fx-resource-appstudio.teamsAppId}}",
    "packageName": "com.microsoft.teams.extension",
    "developer": {
        "name": "Teams App, Inc.",
        "websiteUrl": "{{state.fx-resource-frontend-hosting.endpoint}}",
        "privacyUrl": "{{state.fx-resource-frontend-hosting.endpoint}}{{state.fx-resource-frontend-hosting.indexPath}}/privacy",
        "termsOfUseUrl": "{{state.fx-resource-frontend-hosting.endpoint}}{{state.fx-resource-frontend-hosting.indexPath}}/termsofuse"
    },
    "icons": {
        "color": "resources/color.png",
        "outline": "resources/outline.png"
    },
    "name": {
        "short": "{{config.manifest.appName.short}}",
        "full": "{{config.manifest.appName.full}}"
    },
    "description": {
        "short": "Short description of {{config.manifest.appName.short}}",
        "full": "Full description of {{config.manifest.appName.short}}"
    },
    "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
    "bots": [
        {
            "botId": "{{state.fx-resource-bot.botId}}",
            "scopes": [
                "personal",
                "team",
                "groupchat"
            ],
            "supportsFiles": false,
            "supportsCalling": true,
            "supportsVideo": true,
            "isNotificationOnly": false
        }
    ],
    "composeExtensions": [],
    "configurableTabs": [],
    "staticTabs": [],
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "{{state.fx-resource-aad-app-for-teams.clientId}}",
        "resource": "{{state.fx-resource-aad-app-for-teams.applicationIdUris}}"
    }
}
```

I also believe to have configured the correct permissions on the App Registration in Azure:
[image]

Any idea where to look next? What do I need to do to make the bot directly callable as I would be able to with any other user?

Comment: Did you switch Teams to Developer Preview? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro

Comment: Now I have, thank you. It seems the same bot has calling buttons now in the local installation. But when I start debugging in Visual Studio, it always opens Teams in Edge instead of the locally installed client. Any idea how to change that?

Comment: Please have look into this doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/toolkit/debug-teams-app-visual-studio